# Are all 151 pokémon catchable on the same account?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the classic Pokémon RBY, in order to "catch them all", you had to trade between games because there were some exclusive pokémon you could only get through trading with the other version.

I am wondering whether Niantic did something similar with Pokémon Go, where depending on some hidden value in your account, you can only catch certain pokémon and you will have to catch them all by trading them with other players in a later update.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As it appears right now it is possible to get 146, all of which you can catch or evolve up. The 5 legendary (Articuno, Zapdos, Moltres, Mew, Mewtwo) are uncatchable at least at this time. Whether they are added later or will be rewards for something special is unknown.

Comment: Do you have a source for those legendaries being uncatchable?

Comment: Forgot where it was on Reddit, but a source said they are reserved for special anomaly-like events where the three teams battle it out there.

Comment: @Nzall Doing some digging I haven't found any official word about them being there or not, but so far there isn't any proof they can do found. Here is a database that shows they have been seen 0 times out of "24,00+ sightings" but this doesn't necessarily prove they aren't possible. https://poke-assistant.herokuapp.com/main/pokemonstats

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 I'm not exactly sure. From that database above they show it's possible but I can't exactly say one way or another.

Comment: People have registered mew, mewtwo, zapdos, and articuno on the silph road global pokedex.

These entries are self reported and are not validated by a second party, but several people have made similar claims.

Comment: It's also possible that some Pokemon might be exclusive to some regions - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276389/where-is-the-farfetchd/276391#comment388404_276391

Comment: @TimMalone That is correct but the regionally exclusive ones are still able to be hatched from 10KM eggs I believe.

Answer (score 7):

Keep in mind that the following information has been extracted from the Pokemon Go source code, and while its accuracy may seem feasible and reasonable, **it is not yet official.** That being said, this is what most people seem to believe at this point...

The following a list of the base capture rate for each of the 151 Pokemon in Pokemon Go ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4vs70r/analysis_on_catch_rates_and_encounters/)):

- **Base Capture Rate**: List of Pokemon
- **56%**: Magikarp
- **48%**: Oddish
- **40%**: Caterpie, Weedle, Pidgey, Rattata, Spearow, Ekans, Sandshrew, Nidoran (male), Nidoran (female), Jigglypuff, Zubat, Venonat, Diglett, Meowth, Psyduck, Mankey, Poliwag, Abra, Machop, Bellsprout, Tentacool, Geodude, Slowpoke, Magnemite, Doduo, Seel, Grimer, Shellder, Drowzee, Krabby, Voltorb, Exeggcute, Koffing, Rhyhorn, Horsea, Goldeen, Staryu
- **32%**: Paras, Ponyta, Gastly, Cubone, Tangela, Eevee, Porygon, Omanyte, Kabuto, Dratini
- **24%**: Clefairy, Vulpix, Growlithe, Farfetch'd, Mr. Mime, Scyther, Jynx, Electabuzz, Magmar, Pinsir, Tauros, Gloom
- **20%**: Metapod, Kakuna, Pidgeotto, Nidorina, Nidorino, Poliwhirl, Kadabra, Machoke, Weepinbell, Graveler
- **16%**: Bulbasaur, Charmander, Squirtle, Pikachu, Hitmonlee, Hitmonchan, Lickitung, Chansey, Lapras, Ditto, Aerodactyl, Snorlax, Kangaskhan, Onix, Raticate, Fearow, Arbok, Sandslash, Wigglytuff, Golbat, Parasect, Venomoth, Dugtrio, Persian, Golduck, Primeape, Tentacruel, Slowbro, Magneton, Dodrio, Dewgong, Muk, Cloyster, Haunter, Hypno, Kingler, Electrode, Exeggutor, Weezing, Rhydon, Seadra, Seaking, Starmie
- **12%**: Rapidash, Marowak, Vaporeon, Jolteon, Flareon, Omastar, Kabutops, Vileplume
- **10%**: Butterfree, Beedrill, Pidgeot, Nidoqueen, Nidoking, Poliwrath, Alakazam, Machamp, Victreebel, Golem
- **8%**: Ivysaur, Charmeleon, Wartortle, Raichu, Clefable, Ninetales, Arcanine, Gyarados, Dragonair, Gengar
- **4%**: Venusaur, Charizard, Blastoise, Dragonite
- **0%**: Articuno, Zapdos, Moltres, Mewtwo, Mew

Keep in mind that **base capture rate** means the probability or likelihood that you will catch a Pokemon with a PokeBall, with no throw bonus, curveball, Razz Berry, or any other feature that increases or decreases your likelihood. You can read [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281186/what-are-all-the-factors-which-affect-catch-chance) about what factors can alter catch rate.

So to answer your question, **no, not all 151 Pokemon are catchable on one account**, or on any sum of accounts, for that matter. However, all 151 are indeed attainable on one account, but as it stands currently, they would not all be attained by catching.

From the above statistics, you can see that there are **five** Pokemon that are currently not catchable (with a base capture rate of 0%), including **Articuno, Zapdos, Moltres, Mewtwo, and Mew**. There is speculation that these Pokemon will be "given away" at Niantic events. It is also interesting to note that the ever mysterious **Ditto** has a base catch rate of **16%**, so if anyone can find it, it's not uncatchable.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwMgYFTd_qc) is a helpful video that essentially summarizes all of the above information in a visual, easy to understand fashion.

Answer (score 6):

Pokémon, which are not in the game yet:

1. Ditto
2. Mew
3. Mewtwo
4. Zapdos
5. Moltres
6. Articuno

151 Kanto Pokémon - 6 = 145 catchable Pokémon

However the missing ones exist in the source files of the App: [Also read at this article](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/why-every-pokemon-go-rarity-list-bs-you-arent-finding-ditto-544827).

Comment: "*Ditto*" ...how would you know though?

Comment: @Lilienthal You mean you can only face it after it has used Transform-Attack? :D

Comment: @Lilienthal [look at its face :)](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/File:Duplica_Ditto_Pikachu.png).

Answer (score 6):

Updates per 11/27/2018, Hope this helps:

- Ditto - can be found in the wild
- Mew - Complete A mythical discovery only one per account
- Mewtwo - was a ex raid boss originally then a level 5 raid boss, currently uncatchable
- Zapdos - was a level 5 raid boss and research reward for a month, currently uncatchable
- Moltres - was a level 5 raid boss and research reward for a month, currently uncatchable
- Articuno - was a level 5 raid boss and research reward for a month, currently uncatchable
- All 3 legendary birds have returned as a random chance for the 7 day research rewards in December 2018, this has been extended to include January and February

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear so, as Pokemon that needed to be traded in order to evolve just require candy. The only limiting factor might be your physical location causing only certain Pokemon to be available, though this could also not be true.

Will this be the case for when they (hopefully) update the game to the next Dex? Who knows. But it does seem like trading is coming and it'd be interesting to see it play a bigger part in the game than just trading for a Pokemon you can't catch yourself.