# Where is the Farfetch'd?

Tags: pokemon-go

My question is basically is it possible to catch a Farfetch'd in Canada? or do I need to go to another country to be able to have him?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of: [What are the regional Pokemon?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/277603/4797)

Answer (score 5):

Farfetch'd is not obtainable in your region, it's exclusive to Asia.

[Source 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4ta6tm/updated_rarity_chart/), [Source 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4sx5iz/farfetchd_found_in_korea/)

Comment: This is not an official posting, just another speculation reddit. There an egg chart [here](http://images.en.yibada.com/data/thumbs/full/113514/685/0/0/0/pokemon-go-egg-chart.jpg) that shows "regional" pokemon from eggs(farfetch'd is center-ish), but again, this isn't Niantec's word either. The only ones with the correct answer is them.

Comment: The "community" of the game has pretty much confirmed that Tauros is North American exclusive, Kanghaskhan is Australia, Mr. Mime is Europe, and Farfetch'd is Asia.

Comment: It should be noted that traveling internationally isn't your only hope for having one - they should still hatch from eggs. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277603/what-are-the-regional-pokemon-in-pokemon-go#comment390328_277605

Answer (score 1):

Farftch'ed is only in Japan
Mr. Mime is in Europe
Kangastchan is in Australia