# What are the regional Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have heard that there are some Pokémon that are region specific.  Could someone please clarify which Pokémon are region specific and in which regions that they can be found in?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- Farfetch’d > Asia
- Kangaskhan > Australia
- Mr. Mime > Europe
- Tauros > North America(*)

[image: region specific Pokemon]

*Several communities confirmed those (including [The Silph Road](https://www.reddit.com/r/thesilphroad)), Niantic didn't.*

(*) South America is likely to have Tauros as well. This has been posted on Reddit several times (Tauros apparently got caught in Brazil), but not enough to confirm this as true. Feel free to update this once there's proof. Until then this stands as Tauros is for North America only.

Comment: so the bufallo pokemon is in North America, the Clown Pokemon is in Europe, the Kangaroo pokemon is in Australia and the leek bird pokemon is in Asia? Sounds not stereotypical at all...

Comment: Aw damn, I want a farfetch'd

Comment: @Sidney From my understanding - you can still get all these pokemon from Eggs.

Comment: I can confirm you can get Mr. Mime on Europe by catching it. I got one a few days ago.

Comment: I can confirm Tauros from North America (Canada).

Comment: Are there any other regional Pokemon?  Or at this time is it only these 4 that are known?  Thanks for your initial answer!

Comment: I can confirm both Farfetch'd and Kangaskhan as wild catches in Asia (Japan) and Australia respectively. Also @Nzall Mr. Mime is not the "clown Pokémon" but is in fact as its name suggests, a mime Pokémon.

Comment: @sidney You can still get these from hatching eggs, or traveling.

Comment: I can confirm Tauros in North America (USA). I caught one on the W&OD Trail in Purcellville, Virginia (about an hour away from Washington, DC). I believe the other one I caught was also on a park trail - did anyone else see Tauros in a park?

Comment: That sounds so farfetch'd... *chuckles*

Comment: Does Africa not have one? Or is it the same as another place?

Comment: [Research from the Silph Road subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5ulp9t/a_look_at_the_facts_heracross/?ref=search_posts) suggests A) Heracross is a new exclusive in Gen 2, for Central/South America, and B) there's long been a border (almost but not quite coincident with the southern extent of mainland USA) south of which Tauros could not be found, and now that's the border between Taurus territory and Heracross country.

Comment: According to [Pokemon Go Hub](https://pokemongohub.net/generation-3/plusle-minun/) and other reports, 3rd Gen contains region exclusives. Plusle: North America, South America and Africa; Minun: Europe, Asia and Oceania

Answer (score 17):

Reddit's [r/TheSilphRoad](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/) subreddit has updated a regional map for Generation 2.

[image]

This image shown here is constructed from [this link](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1gOn-ASh7kskCCiHK4A-IHZSwfsk&ll=18.552413426771157%2C-34.7607421875&z=3), supplemented with images from Bulbapedia. The link includes some details about these boundaries, which I will add below.

**Generation 1**

Tauros

> Covers all major Canadian cities, no further North than Calgary, somewhere between 51˚ and 52°N, but the North East section might be a little more unclear. South as far as 29˚N. Heracross starts where it stops

Mr. Mime

> Reported as far North as 61˚, does not cover all of Norway. Not found in Gibraltar but in Northern Tunisia. Found  in Sicily but not Malta. As far West as the Azores. South Eastern border a little more unclear but as far East into Russia as Kazan

Farfetch’d

> All of Japan, South Korea, and reports of Vladivostok and Eastern Russia as well as areas of Northern China. Covers all of Taiwan. Covers all of Hong Kong and any areas of China South of there.

Kangaskhan

> Covers Australia, including Tasmania, as well as Papua New Guinea.

**Generation 2**

Corsola

> No higher than 31˚N and not found more than 300km inland, southern limit still disputed. 26˚S in Australia, Chile, Madagascar and Mauritius, but lower in Brazil. Confirmed in Nairobi most likely due to Lake Victoria being such a large body of water.

Heracross

> Starts at 29˚N and covers the Caribbean, Central and South Americas. Most likely reaches all the way to the Southern tips of Argentina and Chile.

Note that an alternate map slightly adjusts the borders, with it being notable that Corsola do not exist very far inland. The Tauros border also extends farther north into Canada, although not completely covering it. Farfetch'd also covers more parts of China.

Credit to [u/oktimeforplanb post on r/silphroad](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5vj2lc/current_regional_map_please_contribute_further/%5C) (With their image at that link).

Comment: One thing to point out is that this totally leaves out Canada; we're part of North America, and we also get Tauros.  Quite a few, in fact.

Comment: @Frank, The second map I linked suggests the Tauros region extends farther into Canada, slightly past Calgary or Regina

Comment: The second map looks much more precise.  Can you replace the map images?

Comment: @Jerry Map has been replaced

Answer (score -3):

I have caught several wild Tauros in California. Someone also told me that her husband hatched a Kangaskhan from an egg here in the US.

Comment: This is a new answer to a question with an already accepted answer.  What does you answer add that the accepted answer does not?

Comment: @JAL - the OP is showing evidence that the Pokemon are not in fact region-specific.

Answer (score -4):

I have just disproved this theory that there are regional Pokémon! Mr Mime does in fact spawn in the US! I have recently found him in my home state of NJ. So this leads me to believe that the others spawn within the US as well.

Comment: Do you have proof of this?

Comment: @Ash - I think the OP is using personal experience - *I have recently found him in my home state of NJ.*