# What is the "regional Pokémon" for south America?

Tags: pokemon-go

The question: [What are the regional Pokemon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277603/what-are-the-regional-pokemon) does not address South America (hereby referred as SA), basically because at the time of the posting the game had not launched in South America (SA).

**The question linked above was posted before South America launch, and does not address if the north america Pokémon can be caught in South America too. Therefore, not a duplicate.**

Tauros is the Pokémon for North America? Is it the same for SA?

If not, is there any hard evidence of some of the "regional" Pokémon being caught in SA?

Comment: The question you linked describes all the regional pokemon. Ditto still has no spawn so maybe it will also be a regional pokemon, but either way this is still a duplicate.

Comment: @Aequitas that Q&A does not cover south america. Either you edit that question to add info (with sources) covering south america, or drop the duplicate.

Comment: @Mindwin The original question covers anything we officially know, so it covers everything possible. Guesses don't count as proper answers. IMHO this is a dupe. Asking for regionals, while there is already a full list is not a new question.

Comment: The list of regionals known doesn't say anything about South America though.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the regional Pokémon in Pokémon Go. [image]

It shows Mr Mime in Europe, Tauros in the Americas, Farfetch'd in Asia and Kangaskhan in Australia.

To clarify, South America has the same regional Pokémon as North America.

Comment: That does not even remotely answer the question. The asker is clearly aware of these. As seen by the link he posted to the other question related to this. He is asking specifically about south america because that is not covered by the other question.

Comment: @Arperum it does, because this question is a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: It clearly isn't. The game was recently launched in Brazil (South America) and South America is not referenced in that link whatsoever. The answer was written well before the game was even launched in South America, so it cannot be a duplicate.

Comment: OP asked for a Latin regional, not all the others. This answer may be correct, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: South America has the same regional pokemon as North America hence why I wrote Americas, but it seems unclear so I'll edit it.

Comment: Any confirmation for this? I haven't seen anyone getting a Tauros there.

Comment: @dly please "latin regional" <-- don't. All the other regions are by continental divisions, so don't mix in political/ethnical classifications.

Comment: @Riley sources, please.

Comment: @Mindwin I've always learned that "Latin America is South and Middle America." It has nothing to do with ethnicity/politics. [Wikipedia seems to agree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_America)

Comment: @Aequitas if the question is a duplicate of the linked question, the answerer should have flagged to close the question as a dupe, not added an answer.

Comment: @Arperum "middle america" seems to be either the USA heartlnads or a term coined to separate mexico from the rest of north america. Then there's the fact that the geographical region of south (or central) america have other countries that are not latin. So please don't use them interchangeably.

Comment: @Mindwin I used middle in a translation issue probably. I was trying to aim at central america. This is entirely unrelated to the question though, let's continue this on [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge)