# In what countries are region exclusive Pokémon available?

Tags: pokemon-go

There are currently 6 region-exclusive Pokémon:

- Kangaskhan - Australia
- Tauros - North America
- Farfetch’d - Asia
- Mr. Mime - Europe
- Corsola - between 31N° and 26S°
- Heracross - South America

I'm wondering about more precise areas where those Pokémon are available, since, for example, Farfetch’d isn't available in Israel, even though it is in Asia.

What are Niantic's definitions of Asia, Europe, North America, and Australia, with regards to the availability of region-specific Pokémon?

Comment: Isn't that because of the fact the game is not officially out yet in Israel? It might be that the region exclusive pokemon are only available in countries where the game has been released already. Please refer to this list for more information: http://www.releases.com/availability/pokemon-go

Comment: I dont think so, according to the site the game isn't available in Korea, yet I have seen reports that Farfetchd is available there. More likly that by Asia they mean east Asia.

Comment: Are these reports confirmed to be legit? I mean, with the amount of hackers and teleporters nowadays it's actually really easy to get a region exclusive. Are you also 100% sure there is no Farfetch'd anywhere in Israel? I'm from Europe myself but have only seen 2 Mr. Mime in the area's I frequent (level 25).

To get 100% confirmation you could always send a support ticket to Niantic? Who knows it might be an error on their end?

Comment: It's going to be interesting to find out which region-exclusive (if any) will be available in Russia, considering that Russia is both in Europe and Asia.

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks, from looking at the silph road nests atlas, someone reported a nest of mr. mime in Moscow, where the game wasn't released yet.

Answer (score 4):

Based on information from users' reports [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/51tqvd/region_exclusive_specification/?):

#### North America (Tauros):

- Mexico, Canada, and Continental United States *excluding southern Florida*
- Confirmed **unavailable** in Brazil, presumed the same across South America

#### Europe (Mr. Mime):

- Major European countries confirmed (with [another source](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4tnmwq/i_caught_a_mr_mime_in_europe/)): Hungary, Portugal, England, Spain, France, Norway, [Italy](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4wz283/mr_mime_spawn_locations_in_florence_italy/), Turkey, Iceland, [Netherlands](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sp6bo/i_live_near_a_mr_mime_spawn/), [Estonia](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4s14i9/has_anyone_caught_mr_mime/d5jr9sn/), [Sweden](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4wrst7/can_i_find_mrmime_in_stockholmsweden/), [Ireland](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonGoIreland/comments/4xqy0w/mr_mime_nest_in_dublin/), Greece
- Confirmed **unavailable** in Malta, rumors of unavailability in southern Spain

#### Asia (Farfetch'd):

- Japan, Hong Kong, Philippines, Taiwan, South Korea (not officially released, though)
- Confirmed **unavailable** in Singapore, Malaysia, Vietnam

#### Australia (Kangaskhan):

- Confirmed for Australia, reports of spawns at Papua, Indonesia
- Confirmed **unavailable** in New Zealand

(***Note: lists subject to change in the future***)

Comment: I've caught a Mr. Mime in Greece.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed added to the list! I'd actually tried to find somewhere that specified Greece but couldn't, but apparently you already knew :D

Comment: Mr. Meme also spawns in Germany

Answer (score 1):

From my [previous answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/302455/119471):

Reddit's [r/TheSilphRoad](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/) subreddit has updated a regional map for Generation 2.

[image]

This image shown here is constructed from [this link](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1gOn-ASh7kskCCiHK4A-IHZSwfsk&ll=18.552413426771157%2C-34.7607421875&z=3), supplemented with images from Bulbapedia. The link includes some details about these boundaries, which I will add below.

**Generation 1**

Tauros

> Covers all major Canadian cities, no further North than Calgary, somewhere between 51˚ and 52°N, but the North East section might be a little more unclear. South as far as 29˚N. Heracross starts where it stops

Mr. Mime

> Reported as far North as 61˚, does not cover all of Norway. Not found in Gibraltar but in Northern Tunisia. Found  in Sicily but not Malta. As far West as the Azores. South Eastern border a little more unclear but as far East into Russia as Kazan

Farfetch’d

> All of Japan, South Korea, and reports of Vladivostok and Eastern Russia as well as areas of Northern China. Covers all of Taiwan. Covers all of Hong Kong and any areas of China South of there.

Kangaskhan

> Covers Australia, including Tasmania, as well as Papua New Guinea.

**Generation 2**

Corsola

> No higher than 31˚N and not found more than 300km inland, southern limit still disputed. 26˚S in Australia, Chile, Madagascar and Mauritius, but lower in Brazil. Confirmed in Nairobi most likely due to Lake Victoria being such a large body of water.

Heracross

> Starts at 29˚N and covers the Caribbean, Central and South Americas. Most likely reaches all the way to the Southern tips of Argentina and Chile.

Note that an alternate map slightly adjusts the borders, with it being notable that Corsola do not exist very far inland. The Tauros border also extends farther north into Canada, although not completely covering it. Farfetch'd also covers more parts of China.

Credit to [u/oktimeforplanb post on r/silphroad](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5vj2lc/current_regional_map_please_contribute_further/%5C) (With their image at that link).

Comment: I think your answer is great, but it seems like bad form to have identical answers on more than one question.  Maybe this question is a duplicate.